# Double tap on a Flatlist React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-animated, react-native-reanimated

I'm trying to recreate Instagram's double tap on an item and a heart appears for a few seconds. Im currently rendering text items in a flatist (1 item per page) and I want the user to be able to double tap the text section and a heart will appear.

I can't seem to get both the flatList and the animation to work together. Any ideas? In my current code it will only render the flatList and not the Animated.image. I tried wrapping the animated image in an oppress in a touchable without feedback, still no luck

```
  const onDoubleTap = useCallback(() => {
    //console.log("tapped");
    scale.value = withSpring(1, undefined, (isFinished) => {
      if (isFinished) {
        scale.value = withDelay(500, withSpring(0));
        console.log("Double Tapped");
      }
    });
  }, []);

 return (
      <TapGestureHandler
        numberOfTaps={2}
        onActivated={onDoubleTap}
      >
        <Animated.View>
           <FlatList
            horizontal={false}
            decelerationRate={"fast"}
            snapToAlignment={"center"}
            snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("screen").height}
            data={flatl}
            // keyExtractor={(item, index) => `id_${index}`}
            style={styles.fullScreen}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={[{ ...styles.fullHeight }]}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          /> 
          <AnimatedImage
            source={require("../assets/heart.png")}
            style={[
              styles.image,
              rStyle,
            ]}
            resizeMode={"center"}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </TapGestureHandler>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check this out : https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/instagram-style-double-tap-with-react-native-49e757f68de, if it didn't work/inspire you please try to create a snack that shows the problem you're getting